# outputting websites using curl_multi with preg_match_all, site loads slow

Tags: php, curl, foreach, preg-match

I have a script using curl-multi and it scraps through multiple sites for contents. I was wondering what would be a faster way to output certain contents for each site.

```
<?php // Get the tables for 1 website
       preg_match_all("/\<tbody\>(.*?)\<\/tbody\>/is",
            $res[0], $matches );
       foreach($matches[0] as $value)
    {
        echo $value;
    }

    // Get the tables for site 2
       preg_match_all("/\<div class=\"dealsListS\"\>(.*?)\<\/div\>/is",
            $res[1], $matches );
       foreach($matches[0] as $value)
    {
        echo $value;
    }


    // Get the tables for site 3
       preg_match_all("/\<div class=\"city_save\"\>(.*?)\<\/div\>/is",
            $res[2], $matches );
       foreach($matches[0] as $value)
    {
        echo $value;
    }

    // Get the tables for site 4
       preg_match_all("/\<div class=\"offer-stream\"\>(.*?)\<\/div\>/is",
            $res[3], $matches );
       foreach($matches[0] as $value)
    {
        echo $value;
    }
    ?>
```

Need help making it so the page won't load long. this is only a few which I will need to add more to.

Comment: **Don use regex to parse HTML**, use an [html dom parser instead](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this code ?

```
<?php
    function extract_data($html_code, $regex) {
       $buffer="";
       preg_match_all($regex, $html_code, $matches );
       foreach($matches[0] as $value)
       {
          $buffer .= $value;
       }
       return $buffer;
    }

    // Get the tables for 1 website
    $buffer = extract_data("/\<tbody\>(.*?)\<\/tbody\>/is", $res[0]);

    // Get the tables for site 2
    $buffer .= extract_data("/\<div class=\"dealsListS\"\>(.*?)\<\/div\>/is", $res[1]);

    // Get the tables for site 3
    $buffer .= extract_data("/\<div class=\"city_save\"\>(.*?)\<\/div\>/is", $res[2]);

    // Get the tables for site 4
    $buffer .= extract_data("/\<div class=\"offer-stream\"\>(.*?)\<\/div\>/is", $res[3]);

    echo $buffer;
?>
```